# jquery submit to database 1 answer a time

Tags: php, jquery

I've built a quiz using php and currently the answers are displayed all at once, I wondered if I could get them to be displayed two at a time using jquery and have a submit button that would insert the users answer into the database?

currently my code looks like:

```
<?php
//retreive questions from database and put into question box

$query2 = "SELECT `QuestionId`, `Question`, `Opt1`, `Opt2`, `Opt3`, `Opt4`,`Answer` FROM `pf_questions`";

$question2 = mysql_query($query2);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($question2)){

    $id         = $row['QuestionId'];
    $question   = $row['Question'];
    $opt1       = $row['Opt1'];
    $opt2       = $row['Opt2'];
    $opt3       = $row['Opt3'];
    $opt4       = $row['Opt4'];
    $answer     = $row["Answer"];

?>
<div id="ContainerQuestion">
    <span class="Question">Question <?php echo $id; ?>. <?php echo $question; ?></span>

        <p><input type=radio name='q<?php echo $id; ?>' value="a" <?php if($opt1=='a') echo "checked='checked'"' ?>> <?php echo $opt1; ?> </p>
        <p><input type=radio name='q<?php echo $id; ?>' value="b" <?php if($opt1=='b') echo "checked='checked'"' ?>> <?php echo $opt2; ?> </p>
        <p><input type=radio name='q<?php echo $id; ?>' value="c" <?php if($opt1=='c') echo "checked='checked'"' ?>> <?php echo $opt3; ?> </p>
        <p><input type=radio name='q<?php echo $id; ?>' value="d" <?php if($opt1=='d') echo "checked='checked'"' ?>> <?php echo $opt4; ?> </p>


</div>
<?php
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

i built a quick page that contains a simple structure of the javascript required to put you on the right path. just copy paste into a notepad file save as html run and click submit.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
        .Question{
            display:none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <p id="1" class="Question">Question 1</p>
        <p id="2" class="Question">Question 2</p>
        <p id="3" class="Question">Question 3</p>
        <p id="4" class="Question">Question 4</p>
        <button id="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    var AmountToRevealPerItteration = 2;
    var currentIndex=0;
    var questions;
    $(document).ready( function (){
        questions = $("#container").find('.Question').toArray();
        $('#submit').click(function(e){
        for(var counter = 1;counter <= AmountToRevealPerItteration;counter++){
            revealQuestion();
        }
        });
    });

    function revealQuestion(){
        if(currentIndex == questions.length){
            return;
        }
        $(questions[currentIndex]).attr('style','display:block');
        currentIndex++;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: could this work so that question disappears and then question 2 appears in its place?

Comment: ye just add a method before the reveal that hides all the questions on the page

Comment: oooo I've done that - awesome, How can I get the button to say first and last question instead of submit?

Comment: just put a if statement and if you are busy on the first one change text to first question and if youre on the last question in the array change the text to last question

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Ajax. At first fetch 2 questions depending upon your criteria. And then a click on a button to fetch next question (after checking one option as ans from previous question of course). You need to pass some kinda number that tell php script which next records need to be fetched. you can use [jQuery ajax](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax) .